# C# OpenCV: Detecting a Stop Sign

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV on a Windows Forms Application with C#. Looking through the YouTube videos and online tutorials, I could not find anything that works for me or that I was able to make work for me. I believe this is because I am using the latest version of EmguCV, while these videos and tutorials are using 2.x.x.

I am making a science fair project with a Raspberry PI 2 running IoT Core (Microsoft Internet of Things), so I will be deploying code to the PI directly from Visual Studio. My science fair project involves traffic sign detection and speed limit detection.

Should I just downgrade EmguCV? Does anyone have any ideas on how I could go about detecting different traffic signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Emgu installed (if not download and install it from [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation)), you can find in its folder (for example C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal 3.0.0.2157\Solution\VS2010-2015) Emgu.CV.Example.sln, where is a project where you have trrafic sign recognition example.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of it but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for more of a template matching kind of example :)

Comment: Take a look to SURF feature which is used in the sign recognition project or surf feature example project.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at it right now. Can SURF be used with a camera?

Comment: Of course, the SURF does not care where the picture come from. Take a look to video surveilance project, there you can find how to use camera.